# Update marker position in react-native-maps and keep current region

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have one MapView and one marker. I asynchronously request the user current position and set the region p to the map. Every 10 seconds I update the position of the market. This make the region to reset to the p position. To avoid that I implemented the onRigionChange so that when the market state is updated the last region will be kept. This works but make the navigation in the map very buggy. Scrolling and changing the region in the map are not working properly. Can it be that there is a dead lock caused be onregionchange and the region prop? Do you have an idea on how to fix the problem?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    this.setState({ location });
    this.setState({
          region: {
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.003,
            longitudeDelta: 0.003,
          },
        });
      }



state = {
    location: null,
    region:null,
    errorMessage: null,
    marker: {latitude: 0,longitude: 0},
  };

      <MapView style={styles.map}
       showsUserLocation = {true}
       onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
       region={this.state.region} >
       <MapView.Marker
       coordinate={this.state.marker}
       title={"title"}
       description={"description"}/>
       </MapView>
```

Comment: Your present code looks fine. You need to add more info to look in the matter and troubleshoot the problem

Comment: @RishavKumar Code added